# Platform independence in pip requirement files

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

How can I get platform specific things into a requirements file?  Some windows packages are needed instead of their linux counterparts.

WinPExpect  vs pexpect
pywin32 isn't needed on linux but is needed by winpexpect

Any idea of how you could deal with that?

I've thought about a small python script that would detect the platform and deal with it by running pip with different platform specific files as well as the "main" requirements file.  Seems like maybe it should be simpler.

Comment: I have totally same question with pexpect and winpexpect =)!

Answer (score 0):

`pip` requirements do not allow it.

There is a discusion about this feature in [distutils2](http://packages.python.org/Distutils2/). See [PEP 345](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/) for more metadata information.

More info about `distutils2` and metadata: http://packages.python.org/Distutils2/library/distutils2.metadata.html

I don't know the state of PEP 345 and package installers.

Comment: This answer is outdated.  See PEP 508 environment markers. 
 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers

Answer (score 0):

Since this comes up first in a stackoverflow search for `[python] requirements different platforms` allow me to point to this later question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30449557/1124740) and [this one's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057099/1124740); especially since the `distutils2` links in the other answer here are now dead.