# Operating-system specific requirements with pip

Tags: python, operating-system, pip

Is it possible to have OS specific requirements in pip's requirements.txt file?

For example:
I have a dependency on *readline*, therefore, if installing on windows (or OSX), then *pyreadline* is a requirement.  If it's linux, then I don't want to force an install.

Comment: Nope. I don't think so. This should be dealt with some deployment. Also, if this were a project you want to distribute to people to use, never distribute requiremnts.txt.

Comment: @CppLearner never `distribute requirements.txt` ? isn't it its purpose ?

Comment: Well that's what I said "if this were a project". If you are writing a project, use ``setup.py``.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this with "Environment Markers" as specified in [PEP-508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers):

Here's an example of using such a marker inside a `requirements.txt`:

```
pyreadline==2.1; platform_system == "Windows"
```

Similarly, in a `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['pyreadline; platform_system == "Windows"'],
)
```

Comment: With Python 3.7, I had to use a semi-colon in the setup.py file install_requires, like this:

install_requires=["pywin32 > 1.0 ; sys.platform == 'win32'"],

Comment: PEP 496 is *Status: Rejected*. I have updated your post with the appropriate replacement, which is PEP 508. This also accounts for the confusion @electromechanick mentioned.

Comment: FYI Mac system_platform is "Darwin"

Answer (score 4):

In the end, adding the OS check in the setup.py is what I've found other people using.  Ex:

```
install_requires = [
        "parsedatetime >= 1.1.2",
        "colorama >= 0.2.5",
        "pycrypto >= 2.6"
        ] + ["pyreadline >= 2.0"] if "win" in sys.platform else [],
```

[link to full setup.py with example code](https://github.com/maebert/jrnl/blob/9b0bee06376372ea6ecaa3c1c0caad14647c86bd/setup.py)

Comment: Don't use this. This used to be fine when posted (back in the days when the setup.py was executed during installation), but the modern way this works is that a wheel is build that contains everything to install the package.

Comment: wow, this is old....I'll just go ahead and make the other answer the accepted one......