# How to manage pip package for different platforms?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to 'pip freeze' for different platforms.

A given work is to distinguish requirements.txt like common.txt, requirements_amd64.txt, and requirements_mac. Because on Mac, we don't use nvidia gpu. So requirements.txt should be splitted for platform.

Finally I would like to make requirements.txt, where is like:

```
-r common.txt
-r requirements_amd64.txt sys_platform != 'darwin'
-r requirements_arm64.txt sys_platform == 'darwin'
```

A method I thought is to arrange manually.

1. pip freeze > temp.txt
2. select common packages and copy and paste to common.txt
3. select packages for amd64 and copy and paste to requirements_amd64.txt
4. select packages for mac and copy and paste to requirements_mac.txt
5. make requirements.txt

I think, this is inefficiency. Very poor management.

Any other methods or keywords to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operating-system specific requirements with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011379/operating-system-specific-requirements-with-pip)

Comment: @sahasrara62 Sorry. what you present is not about my question. The question you gave is about installing packages for different platforms. What I want is to manage installed packages as some group(directory).