# Installing platform-specific dependencies through PIP

Tags: python, pip, package-managers, requirements.txt

I'm using LDTP in my tests and it comes as two different packages for two different platforms:

- PyAtom on Mac OS;
- LDTP on Linux.

It so happens, that both of them has platform-specific binaries and can't really be installed on other OSes. My question is, how do I make my `requirements.txt` to install packages dependent on platform?

Ideally it should be something like:

```
mac:
  -e git+https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom.git@1ca0c6a0343000286a328268899d1aab376d8e82#egg=atomac-master
linux:
  ldtp==3.5.0
holmium.core==0.7.6
pytest==2.5.2
selenium==2.42.1
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011379/operating-system-specific-requirements-with-pip

Comment: Better:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers

Answer (score 0):

Using the link in @wim's comment (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers), we find `sys_platform` can do the trick.

```
-e git+https://github.com/...#egg=atomac-master;sys_platform=="darwin"
ldtp==3.5.0;sys_platform!="darwin"
holmium.core==0.7.6
pytest==2.5.2
selenium==2.42.1
```

Similar options exists for different Python versions, CPython vs Jython, and many more.

(For historical reasons that I can't remember right now, "darwin" is often the name for MacOS.)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can create a file for each platform requirements:

```
requirements-windows.txt
requirements-linux.txt
requirements-mac.txt
```

and then run for example:

```
pip install -r requirements-mac.txt
```

if you like...